# Error accessing element within iframe using cypress

Tags: jquery, iframe, cypress

I'm fairly new to cypress/javascript/jquery and I'd really appreciate some help! I am trying an approach to accessing an element within an iframe with cypress that was suggested here:  https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/136#issuecomment-525994895.  I'm getting a cypress error with the .its command and subsequent error on the getInDocument custom command.

This is an excerpt of the html code under test:

```
<iframe id="iframeDiag" style="width:100%;height:100%;border:none;padding:0px;z-index:1001;" src="https://<snip>">
#document
<snip>
<button _ngcontent-c11="" class="btn btn-md pointer btn-primary" type="button">Next</button>
<snip>
</iframe>
```

This is the cypress code:

```
cy.get("#iframeDiag")
  .iframeLoaded()
  .its('document')
  .getInDocument('button:contains(Next)')
  .trigger('click')
```

The .get is successful. The .its has this error:

```
cypress_runner.js:126133 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert object to primitive value
at baseToString (cypress_runner.js:126133)
at toString (cypress_runner.js:134455)
at Function.trim (cypress_runner.js:136853)
at cypress_runner.js:157797
at cypress_runner.js:126802
at baseForOwn (cypress_runner.js:124887)
at cypress_runner.js:126771
at Function.forEach (cypress_runner.js:131239)
at Object._logValues (cypress_runner.js:157794)
at Object.logFormatted (cypress_runner.js:157783)
at EventEmitter. (cypress_runner.js:157457)
at EventEmitter.emit (cypress_runner.js:121451)
at EventEmitter. (cypress_runner.js:101916)
at EventEmitter.emit (cypress_runner.js:121451)
at Object.emit (cypress_runner.js:101958)
at Object. (cypress_runner.js:100786)
```

Should I focus on the TypeError? On the face of it, it appears to be a cypress error but I realize it could be the application code under test.

Or can that be ignored and instead I should focus on my selector in the .getInDocument command?

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well, actually, what I thought worked didn't.  The attempt follows in case somebody might see the problem.  I can't give credit to the originator of this approach because I don't remember where I got it (been down the rabbit hole!):

```
it ('Checking Accessibility', () => {
    // inject axe into iframes
    cy.window()
    .then((win) => {
        var iframe = win.document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0];
        console.log('Inject axe into iframe '+iframe.id);
        var script = iframe.contentWindow.document.createElement("script");
        script.src = '../js/axe.min.js';
        script.type = 'text/javascript';
        iframe.contentWindow.document.body.appendChild(script);
        //wait(6000);
        const axe = require('axe-core');
        return win.axe.run(iframe, { iframes: true} );
    })
    .then(({ violations }) => {
        if (violations.length) {
            cy.wrap(violations, { log: false }).each(v => {
                Cypress.log({
                    name: 'a11y error!',
                    consoleProps: () => v,
                    message: `${v.id} on ${v.nodes.length} Node${
                        v.nodes.length === 1 ? '' : 's'
                        }`
                })  
            })
        }
      return cy.wrap(violations, { log: false })
    })
    .then(violations => {
        assert.equal(
            violations.length,
            0,
            `${violations.length} accessibility violation${
            violations.length === 1 ? '' : 's'
            } ${violations.length === 1 ? 'was' : 'were'} detected`
        )
    })
});
```

I do get accessibility violations so axe is working but nothing from within the iframe (and violations within the iframe do exist).